# Program committee count as scientific achievements?

Tags: program-committee

In general, should pc members/chairs count as scientific achievements?

Comment: What's a program committee? Please consider defining and providing context for people not from your subfield. Also, where are you counting your scientific achievements at? your cv? a webpage?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the program (or other) committee for a conference, especially a major conference in your field, then an item in the CV under a heading like "Service to the Academic Community" is appropriate.

But it isn't a "scientific achievement" in any sense since it is more of a managerial function than anything.